# WebClient close application when download completes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webclient

I'm downloading a huge file (700+MB) using WebClient. When the download completes, the application just closes itself. I tried debugging, but cannot capture anything.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.100/FileServer/crypto.bin"));

    }
}
```

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Have you tried putting a try/catch around it and seeing if you catch anything?

Comment: I did. As I said, I cannot capture anything. The application just close itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you must declare de `wc` variable outside the initializer.

```
    WebClient wc;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.100/FileServer/crypto.bin"));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an event, something like for example:

```
Private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
  webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt"), @"c:\myfile.txt");
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
}
```

Comment: The real code is very long and include a lot of stuff including complete event handler. I posted short code because I narrowed down the problem. And FYI, I already did what you said, but completed handler was never executed.